# how to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}(n^k)/(\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_in^i)<\infty$?

Tags: limits

for $k\ge 0 \:\text{ (constant)}, a_k\in \Bbb R^+, a_0...a_{k-1}\in \Bbb R$

How can I show that:
$\:\lim_{n\to \infty}(n^k)/(\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_in^i)<\infty$?

I thoght about saying:
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(n^k)/(\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_in^i)=\lim_{n\to \infty}1/(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(a_in^i)/n^k)=1/a_k <\infty$

Comment: That is a nice way. You can probably use $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{i-k} = 0$ for $i < k$ without proof. If not, a proof of that isn't difficult.

Answer (score 1):

** Hint**:

We may suppose $n\ge 1$. Factor out $n^k$ in the denominator and deduce that the quotient has a (finite) limit, then apply the definition of a limit.